# Syntax to include null or blank within "IN" list?

Tags: drools

What is the proper syntax to include a blank or null option within an IN list?
I've unsuccessfully tried various options with the intent to say::
If CLASS-**A** = *ABC *and CLASS-**B** is either *VALUE1*, *VALUE2*, *VALUE3 *-- **or there is NO CLASS-B**...

I've tried NULL, null, Null, as well as "" and " " - thought maybe there is something obvious I am missing.

```
calcrt.get("CLASS-A") == ("ABC") &&
    calcrt.get("CLASS-B") in ("VALUE1" , "VALUE2" , "VALUE3", NULL)
```

Appreciate any guidance - total noob here!

Comment: well since this is a java-based syntax (even if using mvel), it's `null` not any of those other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `null` and `""` in a list with `in` operator:

```
MyObject( someValue in (null, "", "1", "something", "hello world!") )
```

Will match:

- `MyObject{ someValue: null }`
- `MyObject{ someValue: "" }`
- `MyObject{ someValue: "1" }`
- `MyObject{ someValue: "something" }`
- `MyObject{ someValue: "hello world!" }`

Will not match:

- `MyObject{ someValue: " " }` (whitespace is not null or an empty string)

---

That being said, if you're working with a Map and you're checking that something is not present, you may want to consider the case that a 'null' for `get("Class-B")` might not mean the key is not present, but rather that the value is null.  In that case you might consider checking that "Class-B" is present in the keyset.

```
rule "no class-b"
when
  $inputs: Map( this["CLASS-A"] == "ABC" )
  Set( this not contains "CLASS-B" ) from $inputs.keySet()
then
  System.out.println("CLASS-A is ABC and there is no CLASS-B");
end

rule "class-b meets some criteria"
when
  $inputs: Map( this["CLASS-A"] == "ABC",
                this["CLASS-B"] in ("VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3") )
then
  System.out.println("CLASS-A is ABC and CLASS-B is VALUE1/2/3");
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and for the reminder to check for presence.